# Overwrite value in CustomActionData WIX

Tags: wix

I send data to custom action

```
<Property Id="MESSAGE" Value="null"/>
<CustomAction Id="TurnOffServicesEvent" BinaryKey="PathCustomAction" DllEntry="TurnOffServices" Return="check" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>
<CustomAction Id="SendPropertyOff" Property="TurnOffServicesEvent" Value="MESSAGE=[MESSAGE]" />
```

in TurnOffServices

```
session.CustomActionData["MESSAGE"] = "WARN";
```

And when I again reference to this propoerty but in

```
<CustomAction Id="TestAction" BinaryKey="PathCustomAction" DllEntry="Test" Return="check" Execute="immediate"/>
```

And in custom action:

```
session["MESSAGE"] == "null"
```

It seems to me that I don't have reference to the property MESSAGE, that's why it happens. But I have no idea how to make that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found information it isnt possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/win32/msi/obtaining-context-information-for-deferred-execution-custom-actions?redirectedfrom=MSDN

I solved that write information to .txt and read it in next action.